# inheritance of permissions in folders

Tags: inheritance, permissions, active-directory, directory

At my company we use shared folders inside our LAN. Permissions to get into those folders are managed by `Active Directory`, by using security groups.
The problem I have is users need to use again and again the same (empty) folder structure to create new (standards) projects inside our network folders. So, this "folders template" has several subfolders inside, and one of them has different permissions, that are not inherited of its mother folder. 
I configured this subfolder to not inherit permissions. But when users copy/paste (using `Win XP`) this "folders template" inside any other folder this not-inherit option is not copied. And so, this subfolder get the wrong permissions.

What I need is a way to avoid this loss on inheritance when users copy/paste this folder template. Because they won't tell me they did it, and I have no way to know that I must to change inheritance manually.
I don't know if there is a nice way to do it...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth while reading this article over at Microsoft about permission handling when copying/moving files. It does offer a possible solution for your scenario:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316

Best of luck.